# Error when calling method from different class

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a robot in java and I'm having a problem calling methods from different classes. I can call `DriveSystem` fine from a different class and I can call `preset` methods from `DriveSystem`, but whenever I try to call methods that I wrote, `NetBeans` underlines the method. I've tried doing this with different classes and methods, and it gives me the same error, which says `"cannot find symbol   method doNothing()"`.

```
public class DriveDoNothing extends CommandBase {

    public DriveDoNothing() {
        requires(DriveSystem);
    }


    protected void execute() {
        DriveSystem.doNothing();

    }
}
```

**Drive System code:**
DriveSystem is

```
public class DriveSystem extends Subsystem {
  public void doNothing() {        
  leftMotor.set(0.0);        
  rightMotor.set(0.0);   
 }
```

Comment: Where is the code for the DriveSystem class?  The compiler is telling you that there is no `static` method named `doNothing` in that class.  Maybe you wrote an instance method with that name?  You can't call an instance method if you don't have an instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create instance of `DriveSystem`. Since, `doNothing()` is an instance method of `DriveSystem`.

```
new DriveSystem().doNothing();
```

instead of

```
  DriveSystem.doNothing();
```

**Or** either you should change your `doNothing()` method to static type.